# How to stop audio session "outputVolume" observer as it is crashing on when we try to remove the server

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

```swift
func listenVolumeButton(){
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: [])
        audioSession.addObserver(self as! NSObject, forKeyPath: "outputVolume",
                                 options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        audioLevel = audioSession.outputVolume
        print("Value is \(audioLevel)")
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}

override  func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "outputVolume" {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        if audioSession.outputVolume > audioLevel {
            print("Hello up key pressed")
            
            if audioSession.outputVolume < audioLevel {
                print("Hello down key pressed")
                
                audioLevel = audioSession.outputVolume
                print(audioSession.outputVolume)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When we try to remove the observer app is crashing

```swift
audioSession.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume")
```

It is crashing by giving the following reason

> **'Cannot remove an observer or the key path "outputVolume" from <AVAudioSession 0x2817259d0> because it is not registered as an observer.'**

Comment: Where is code for removing Observer?

Comment: Check at the bottom "audioSession.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume")" @Kudos

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you switch to modern KVO syntax with block:

```swift
var outputVolumeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

func listenVolumeButton(){
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: [])
        outputVolumeObservation = audioSession.observe(\.outputVolume) { audioSession, _ in
            if audioSession.outputVolume > audioLevel {
                print("Hello up key pressed")

                if audioSession.outputVolume < audioLevel {
                    print("Hello down key pressed")

                    audioLevel = audioSession.outputVolume
                    print(audioSession.outputVolume)
                }
            }
        }
//      audioLevel = audioSession.outputVolume
//      print("Value is \(audioLevel)")
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

It'll automatically unsubscribe when `outputVolumeObservation` become `nil`, like when object is released: no need to call it explicitly in `deinit`.

If you need to stop listening manually, just set it to `nil`:

```swift
func stopListeningVolumeButton() {
    outputVolumeObservation = nil
}
```

Comment: But what is wrong in Questionier code?

Comment: @Kudos not enough information about where `removeObserver` is called from, but this solution is more stable

Comment: @PhilipDukhovremoveObserver was called in viewwillDisappear.

Comment: @Pratik and when `listenVolumeButton` is called?

Comment: Seems to work better than code from the question. I was having crash issues due to background-foreground of app. Seems that the crash is not happening now.

Answer (score 0):

When `removeObserver` again， it triggers,

like the following code:

```
func listenVolumeButton(){
        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true, options: [])
            audioSession.addObserver(self as! NSObject, forKeyPath: "outputVolume",
                                     options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
            audioLevel = audioSession.outputVolume
            print("Value is \(audioLevel)")
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
        
        audioSession.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume")
        audioSession.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume")
        
    }
```

It crashes, and Xcode reports:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 

reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <aaaa.ViewController 0x106a06e90> for the key path "outputVolume" from <AVAudioSession 0x281020370> 

because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

---

As for you, `removeObserver` should not be called in `viewwillDisappear`, but in `deinit{}`

for example, your controller is `B`

- **`ctrl A`** **->** `ctrl B` *->* *`ctrl C`*
- *`ctrl A`* *<-* `ctrl B` **<-** **`ctrl C`**
- `ctrl B` *->* *`ctrl C`*,  `removeObserver` one time,
- *`ctrl A`* *<-* `ctrl B`. `removeObserver` again and crash